# React Typescript how works onMouseEnter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have a component like:

```
const Componen: FC<Props> = ({}) => {

   const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");

   return (
     <ChildComponent onMouseEnter={() => setTitle("some title")} />
     {title}
   )
}
```

i already define a type to ChildComponent for this event.

```
type ChildProps = {
  onMouseEnter?: () => void;
};
```

but nothing happened. So `onMouseEnter` to `ChildComponent` setTitle not works

Comment: Well now you need to call `onMouseEnter` in your child component by binding this event to a an HTML element and not a component

Comment: Can you post the contents of `ChildComponent` as well?

Comment: Why? i can't use this events directly on components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onMouseEnter` isn't an `eventHandler` here but just a prop to `ChildComponent` and it needs to be used by the `ChildComponent` and passed on to a wrapping div

```
const Componen: FC<Props> = ({}) => {

   const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");

   return (
     <ChildComponent onMouseEnter={() => setTitle("some title")} />
     {title}
   )
}

const ChildComponent: FC<Props> = ({ onMouseEnter }) => (
   <div onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}>
       {/* rest of code */}
   </div>
)
```

Comment: sorry i did it :)